# How to put final dot after closing quotes in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quotes

I'm writing an essay in RMarkdown and I'd like to display the dot at the end of the sentence. 
I'm using the `"` character both for open and close the quote. Obviously, I'm inserting the dot after the closing quotes but what is shown is this:

[image]

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\geometry{left = 3cm, right = 3cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm}
\graphicspath{{img}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
\sectionfont{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright}
\subsubsectionfont{\itshape\raggedright}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
```

And this is my code (text) that shows what is reported in the previous image:

```
"...tutto sia correlato con tutto il resto, ma oggetti vicini siano più correlati di oggetti lontani".
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the actual code, don't just describe it.

Comment: Agreed with Gregor - when I create a markdown document with a period after the last quote, it's preserved that way in all of html, pdf, and Word. Not sure why it's doing something funny for you without more details.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was so useful in this case. I edited the question with the preamble and one of the faulty sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
---
title: "Test Table"
date: '2021-11-11'
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{csquotes}

output:
  pdf_document
---

\enquote{I love StackOverflow}.
```

[image]

---

**Addition**

```
\setquotestyle[quotes]{french}
\enquote{I love StackOverflow}.
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you. But it change that kind of quotes with «...».

Comment: @FranzGoogle Look at an addition ;)

Comment: Now it's perfect. Thank you so much!